# Are here two subjects?

Tags: grammar

> I will leave the world to convince you

Acutely *world* here object but I think  two subjects do action here as  *world* and *I*,  but which one will convince *you*, *world* or *I*?

Will world be released by me to convince you, or am I going to leave the world to  convince you by myself?

Answer (score 4):

This is a clear case of [syntactic ambiguity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_ambiguity). There is no way to know for sure without the context.